# Create table of unique foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-key-relationship, unique-constraint, create-table

I am using MySQL and I have two tables of the form :

```
mysql> describe ing_categories;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID_Category | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category    | varchar(64)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe ing_titles;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID_Title | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title    | varchar(128)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have a third table containing foreign key records, the foreign keys are to the above tables:

```
mysql> describe ing_title_categories;
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID_Title_Category | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ID_Title          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ID_Category       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

How do I create the `ing_titles_categories` table so that the *pair* of foreign keys is unique?

Here is my SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE ing_title_categories
(
    ID_Title_Category INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_Title INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ID_Category INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_title(ID_Title)
        REFERENCES ing_titles(ID_Title)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_category(ID_Category)
        REFERENCES ing_categories(ID_Category)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I've searched other questions and they involve making an index for the foreign keys; but I don't want to index by the foreign keys, I want the constraint to be `unique` **for the pair of foreign keys**.

*Tools:*
MySQL Server version: 5.6.26

*Notes:*

1. I am not using PHP, but C++ via MySQL C++ Connector, so please no PHP
   examples.

Comment: your question has NOTHING to do with php, or c/c++. it's purely an SQL problem... that being said, `primary key (ID_Title, ID_Title_Category)`?

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with PHP, but many examples and tutorials on the internet assume the database is accessed via PHP.

Comment: but the sql remains the same, regardless, so the tutorials would still be relevant. it'd be like saying "oh, I can't use this gift because it arrived via FedEx, and I only deal with UPS"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a unique or primary key constraint.  Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE ing_title_categories
(
    ID_Title_Category INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_Title INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ID_Category INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_title(ID_Title)
        REFERENCES ing_titles(ID_Title)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_category(ID_Category)
        REFERENCES ing_categories(ID_Category)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    UNIQUE (ID_Title, ID_Category)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The implementation of the unique constraint *does* create an index.  However, that index is needed to enforce the constraint.  It will also be used for queries, where appropriate.

Note that this is equivalent to:

```
create unique index idx_ing_title_categories_2 on ing_title_categories(ID_Title, ID_Category);
```

One advantage of putting the constraint in the `CREATE TABLE` statement is that you can use the `CONSTRAINT` keyword to give the constraint a meaningful name -- useful when you want to figure out what is happening when the constraint is violated.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `UNIQUE KEY` constraint on both columns `ID_Title` and `ID_Category` as composite unique (`UNIQUE(ID_Title , ID_Category)`) key which will make sure that combination of the said key columns are always unique.

```
ALTER TABLE ing_title_categories
   ADD CONSTRAINT uniqueconstraint UNIQUE(`ID_Title` , `ID_Category`);
```